# shedlock - using without spring @Scheduled annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, shedlock

I am trying to figure out how to utilize shedlock (4.0.0 version) without spring's @scheduled annotation. I am implementing SchedulingConfigurer.configureTasks as below to add a trigger task for my scheduled method.

```
@Component
public class EndpointSubTypeUpdateWorkerManager implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("priorityThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
    private TaskExecutor executor;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("poolScheduler")
    private TaskScheduler scheduler;

   @Autowired
    private LockProvider lockProvider;

    AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(scheduler);
        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startWorkerThreads();
                log.debug("Running Schedular..." + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            }
        }, new Trigger() {
            @Override
            public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                Calendar nextExecutionTime = new GregorianCalendar();
                Date lastActualExecutionTime = triggerContext.lastActualExecutionTime();
                nextExecutionTime.setTime(lastActualExecutionTime != null ? lastActualExecutionTime : new Date());
                nextExecutionTime.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, getNewExecutionTime());
                return nextExecutionTime.getTime();
            }
        });
    }

    @SchedulerLock(name = "EndpointSubTypeUpdateWorkerManager_startWorkerThreads",
            lockAtLeastFor = "2M", lockAtMostFor = "14M")
    public void startWorkerThreads() {
```

I have tried to put in the @SchedulerLock annotation on the startWorkerThreads() method above but I see the following debug statement in the logs

```
2020-05-09 18:53:48,433 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler1] DEBUG net.javacrumbs.shedlock.spring.aop.SpringLockConfigurationExtractor - Unknown task type com.west.schoolmessenger.globaldestinationregistry.worker.EndpointSubTypeUpdateWorkerManager$1@465885e5
2020-05-09 18:53:48,433 [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler1] DEBUG net.javacrumbs.shedlock.core.DefaultLockManager - No lock configuration for com.west.schoolmessenger.globaldestinationregistry.worker.EndpointSubTypeUpdateWorkerManager$1@465885e5. Executing without lock.
```

I read that i can invoke shedlock outside using below code but not sure how can I integrate with my setup above

```
LockingTaskExecutor executor = new DefaultLockingTaskExecutor(lockProvider);
...
Instant lockAtMostUntil = Instant.now().plusSeconds(600);
executor.executeWithLock(runnable, new LockConfiguration("lockName", lockAtMostUntil));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `net.javacrumbs.shedlock.spring.LockableTaskScheduler` in `ScheduledTaskRegistrar`